# Travelling through maze recursively & inserting nodes in all spaces

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, struct, nodes

I have a maze program that takes 5 mazes and inserts nodes into the outlines of those mazes. I'm creating a directed graph that can represent the freespaces in the maze by placing a graph node at each free space grid location and connecting them together with edges.

I'm stuck on a function that actually involves filling the freespaces of the maze with nodes and connecting them. The nodes don't need to follow a certain pattern at the moment, they just need to fill up all empty space like the images shown below. My program right now just displays a blank maze with no nodes.

I'm given a set of guidelines which are commented in `computeGraph()`, but I am really stumped as to how I would trace a maze recursively. My code under the function is gibberish and doesn't do anything. I'm really lost as to what to do and would appreciate some help or guidance. I'm not asking for anything else in the program to be touched, only `computeGraph()` as it's my problem right now. Also I should mention that I'm not allowed to create any extra arrays for this task which makes the problem even harder.

If the comments are not enough, basically the function's purpose is to allocate space for the new graph and return it. Each node of the graph must be dynamically-allocated and connected by setting the appropriate Node up/down/left/right pointers.

Thanks again for any help. I can post the full code/all the files for the program if required, but I just posted only what I thought was necessary for this particular problem.

maze.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "graphSet.h"
#include "mazeDisplay.h"

// Compute the graph for the given maze and add it to the given graph set.
Graph *computeGraph(char maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {

  // Create the initially-empty graph
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
      maze[i][j] = '\0';
    }
  }

  // Find a starting node, then trace out the maze recursively.  A starting node can be
  // found by searching from top to bottom, left to right, for a non-wall maze location.
  // You MUST NOT hard-code this start location ... it must be determined by your code.

  Node *newNode;
  Node *currNode;
  Node *prevNode;

  currNode = *rootNode;
  currPos[0][0];
  prevNode = NULL;
  while(currNode != NULL){
    if(currPos[0][0] == maze[x][y]){
      break;

    }

    prevNode = currNode;
  }


  newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if(prevNode->up != 1){
    prevNode->up = newNode;
  }else if(prevNode->down != 1){ 
    prevNode->down = newNode;
  }else if(prevNode->left != 1){ 
    prevNode->left = newNode;
  }else if(prevNode->right != 1){
    prevNode->right = newNode;
  }

  // To trace out the maze recursively, you will likely want to create a recursive
  // procedure that is called by this one.   It should take parameters to indicate
  // the location in the maze to start tracing from, the maze itself and also the node
  // that led to this node (i.e., the previous one in the tree that led here).  If you
  // start with the root node, then the previous node should be NULL.
  //
  // As you go through the maze, make sure to mark off maze locations that you have
  // visited (perhaps by putting a '2' character at that location) so that you do not
  // go back to that location again and end up with infinite recursion.  So you can
  // stop the recursion when you reach a wall (i.e., a '1' character in the maze) or a
  // '2' character.  A '0' character means that it is a free space that you just arrived
  // at for the first time.   Make sure to check recursively in all directions.  In my
  // solutions (shown on the assignment), I used an ordering of up/down/left/right.  So
  // if you want solutions to look like mine, you should follow that ordering as well.
  //
  // As you traverse the maze, make sure to connect the previous node to the current one.
  // You'll have to check which direction you can from (i.e., x and y values) so that
  // you know whether it is the up/down/left or right pointer to set.

}



// This procedure must clean up graph by removing all nodes in which the previous and
// next nodes have the same x or y value as it.
void cleanUpGraph(Node *n, Node *previousNode) {

}



// This is where it all begins
int main() {
  char mazes[5][HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
    {"111111111111111111111",
     "100000001000100000001",
     "101111111010111011111",
     "100000000010000010001",
     "101110111111101110111",
     "100010001000000000001",
     "111011111111111110111",
     "101010001000100000001",
     "101110111011101011101",
     "100010000000001010001",
     "101010111011111111111",
     "101000001000100000001",
     "101111111110101111101",
     "100010100000100000101",
     "111110101110101111101",
     "100010001000000010101",
     "101010111111111010111",
     "101010001000000010001",
     "101111111010111011101",
     "100000000010001000001",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "101111111111111111101",
     "101111111111111111101",
     "101000100010001000101",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "100010001000100010001",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101110111011101110111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111101111101111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111001111111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111101",
     "100111111111111111001",
     "100011111111111110001",
     "100001111111111100001",
     "100000111111111000001",
     "100000011111110000001",
     "100000001111100000001",
     "100000000111000000001",
     "100000000010000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111110111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "111100000000000000001",
     "111000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111111"}};

  // Open a display window
  openDisplayWindow();



  // Allocate a GraphSet to store the graphs for each maze
  GraphSet *gSet;

  // Compute the graphs for each maze and add them to a Graph Set
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    Graph *g = computeGraph(mazes[i]);

    // Add g to gSet properly
    // ...
  }

  // Show the graphs
  Graph *g; // ... set this to the first graph in gSet ...

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    drawMaze(mazes[i]);  // Draw the maze
    // drawGraph(g->rootNode);    // Draw the graph

    getchar();  // Wait for user to press enter

    // cleanUpGraph(g->rootNode, NULL);   // Clean up the graph
    // drawMaze(mazes[i]);
    // drawGraph(g->rootNode);

    // ... get the next graph in the set ...
    // ... INSERT A LINE OF CODE HERE ...

    getchar();  // Wait again for the user to press ENTER before going on to the next maze
  }

  // Free up all allocated memory
  // ...

  // Close the display window
  closeDisplayWindow();
}
```

graphSet.h:

```
// This struct represents a single intersection/Node in a maze.  It keeps track
// of the x(i.e., column) and y (i.e. row) of the intersection in the maze
// as well as the Nodes in all 4 directions around it).   NULL is used to
// indicate that no Node is beside it in a particular direction.
typedef struct nd {
  int        x;
  int        y;
  struct nd *up;
  struct nd *down;
  struct nd *left;
  struct nd *right;
} Node;


// This struct represents a single maze graph
typedef struct gr {
  Node       *rootNode;
  struct gr  *nextGraph;
} Graph;


// This struct represents a set of maze graphs
typedef struct {
  Graph  *firstGraph;
  Graph  *lastGraph;
} GraphSet;
```

[image: maze pics]

Comment: "The nodes don't need to follow a certain pattern" and "I am really stumped as to how I would traverse a maze recursively", do you see the connection of those two statements? That is where your problem is.

Comment: Can your question be reduced to "How can I travel through an unknown maze so that I am guaranteed to visit each reachable room and also know when I am done"? That is the algorithm you need. Or is there more? In that case please focus this question on a single topic, the one you need to solve first. When that is done ask another separate question on the next problem.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the title. Hopefully that helps. I will need to have the nodes follow a pattern eventually, but I guess for this question I just need the nodes to fill up the empty spaces of the maze like in the pics.

Answer (score 0):

The mazes as shown can be interpreted as a series of single-square rooms, which are connected by "doors" whereever two empty squares touch.
That way, this problem is simpliefied to an undirected graph of identical rooms.
I just repeat this, though I am convinced that you already arrived at this view yourself.

The goal is hence to visit each room and know when all have been visited.

Then the goal to malloc for each empty space (but not more than once) can be achieved by mallocing only when visiting a square for the first time, which can be guaranteed by using a flag set when visiting a new room, at the same time when mallocing. These flags can be "added" to each room, by mirroring the data structure which stores the "empty"/"wall" info.

The remaining goal is to make sure that each empty square gets visited, as long as it CAN be visited. For that I propose to use the "left hand rule" for maze visiting: "Always leave a room through the exit to left of where you entered." It is basically a traversal for directed graphs, similar to the most widely used traversal for binary trees. I.e. for possible exits to North, East, Sout, West, North, always exit through the "next" exit in this order.

The lefthand rule is only for directed graphs without "loops"/"circles", with is of course NOT applicable to your kind of mazes.
To solve that problem, use the ariadne thread. It is a path through all the already visited rooms. Note that you need a path data structure, a flag for each room is not sufficient to keep track of the ariadne thread.

If while using the left-hand-rule you enter a room you have already visited (i.e. it is already found in the path you travelled), then do not enter it and select the next exit, as if the first selected exit does not exist. Imagine the "door" to be locked there. When you are out of exits to unvisited rooms, go back along the ariadne thread until you again find yet unused exits to yet unvisited rooms.

When you are forced to go back to the first room you visited, then you have visited all rooms.

As described above, you ariadne thread grows longer while returning during the search for unvisited rooms. For more efficient implementation, you can shorten the ariadne thread on your way back and rely on the mirrored flags for "already malloced". I.e. the room to go back to is found in the previous entry of the path, while the decision whether to enter a room can be based on the flag.

In your sample solutions, imagine the red dots to be the flags, while the blue lines represent the (unshortened) ariadne thread, which is everywhere double (on the way in and the way out).

Take pen and paper (with an empty version of the maze).
Play the person walking through the maze, draw the blue ariadne thread. Like that it will be possible to follow the description I provided.

Then program it.